# Migrating storage without creating a new storage item

Tags: pallet, storage, migration

I am using Substrate V3 (using decl_storage) and have an existing storage defined like this:

```rust
pub Foo get(fn get_foo) config(): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) u32 => H160;
```

I would like to change this into:

```rust
pub Foo get(fn get_foo) config(): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) H160 => u32;
```

After reading about storage migration, I am planning to use `StorageKeyIterator` to iterate over the old values and `drain` it:

```rust
    for (idx, address) in StorageKeyIterator::<u32, H160, Blake2_128Concat>::
            new(b"PalletName", b"Foo").drain() {

        <Foo>::insert(address, index);
    }
```

My questions are:

- Is this the correct approach?
- Can I reuse the same storage name for old and new value (`Foo`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, there are several ways to achieve this target.

First, you can define a new Storage(or prefix) which we call it tmp, after you write all the data into this tmp storage, you can use `move_prefix` to rename tmp to your original storage name.

Second, you can use the unhash api to do more dangerous business, ref to [unhash](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/storage/unhashed/fn.put_raw.html). Use unhash, you just construct the storage key, and storage value and put_raw.

As, you can see, above two approach have their own benefits and drawbacks, choose one and test seriously.

At last, no matter when you want to do storage migration, make sure you have test it with try-runtime thoroughly.